# WPF using vlc.net

Tags: c#, wpf, vlc

I'd like to use VLC.net. I downloaded via nuget vlc.net.wpf.

Here's the sample code from [Codeplex](https://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Wpf).

```
VlcContext.LibVlcDllsPath = CommonStrings.LIBVLC_DLLS_PATH_DEFAULT_VALUE_AMD64;
//Set the vlc plugins directory path
VlcContext.LibVlcPluginsPath = CommonStrings.PLUGINS_PATH_DEFAULT_VALUE_AMD64;

//Set the startup options
VlcContext.StartupOptions.IgnoreConfig = true;
VlcContext.StartupOptions.LogOptions.LogInFile = true;
VlcContext.StartupOptions.LogOptions.ShowLoggerConsole = true;
VlcContext.StartupOptions.LogOptions.Verbosity = VlcLogVerbosities.Debug;

//Initialize the VlcContext
VlcContext.Initialize();
```

I can't find the `VlcContext` class in Vlc.DotNet.Core (ver 2.1.62.0).
How can I write code using Vlc.net?

Comment: What does this have to do with WPF?

Comment: I have to display a lot of contents.For example two, or three video, and effect object simultaneously.
I'm using MediaElement. But using media element is not smooth.
Then I am searching other method as Display movie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is likely to be that you're looking at the Codeplex documentation, which is now outdated/discontinued, instead of the Github documentation: https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet . There are sample files included with the library download that should help you figure out how things are put together. The Vlc.DotNet library is currently in a relatively beta phase - not everything works, still some kinks being ironed out.